# Как загнать данные из OleDbDataReader в datagridview

Tags: c#

получаю данные таким образом

```
string sqlString = "SELECT PRODUKT, NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ";

OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data      Source=e:\\;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;");

OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, oleConn);

OleDbDataReader oleReader;

 oleConn.Open();

  oleReader = oleCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

есть такое

```
 while (oleReader.Read())
 {
    MessageBox.Show(oleReader[tr].ToString());
    tr++;
 }
```

но как правильно загнать в datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [DataTable.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx), а затем укажите DataTable как источник данных для DataGridView ([DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: пишу так 

                string sqlString = "SELECT PRODUKT, NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ";
                OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=e:\\;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;");
                OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, oleConn);
                OleDbDataReader oleReader;
                oleConn.Open();
                oleReader = oleCmd.ExecuteReader();
                int tr = 0;        
                dt.Load(oleReader);

Comment: пишет Сообщение об исключении = "Поставщик не смог определить значение Decimal. Например, строка только что была создана, значение по умолчанию для столбца Decimal не было доступно, а потребитель еще не задал нового значения Decimal.", Тип исключения = "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: пишу так 

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, oleConn);
                oleConn.Close();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
та же ошибка

Comment: @anunak, а на какой строчке ошибка выскакивает? Скорее всего что-то не так с базой

Comment: получилось. ошибка децимал в столбце с дробными числами